# Postgres change Encoding SQL_ASCII to UTF8

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

i want to change database encoding sql ascii to utf8 without drop database it is possible? (psql 9.5)
(I'm afraid of data disruption)

I'm trying this but doesn't work

```
 update pg_database set encoding = pg_char_to_encoding('utf8') where datname = 'name'
```

[image: postgre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to necessarily `drop` the database. However, you will need to effectively create another one with the new encoding, so changing the encoding really isn't possible to do without data disruption.

In general, the preferred method is to use *pg_dump* to dump the current database, create a new database with utf8 encoding, and do a *pg_restore* to that database.

However, along the way, you may find that there are data-related problems that must be fixed in order for the pg_restore to not fail, as there can be many things stored in a sql_ascii-encoded database (which despite its name is really the absence of any encoding -- it basically just takes the bytes as they are) that are not valid UTF8.

Comment: so how to fix this invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd9 0x27
during import the dump file?

Comment: @aldo: You would need to manually fix the encoding in the database for that occurrence such that the pg_dump and pg_restore will then succeed. It unfortunately may be a very iterative process. Exactly how you "fix" the encoding depends on your business use case(s).